# Android App not updating on wifi

Tags: android, wifi, auto-update

I've an app on playstore...today i've updated a new version, but it isn't getting auto updated on wifi on my phone (that's my phone setting on google play). I'm confused bcoz 7 other apps got updated on my phone but not this one...Can anyone help?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Did you add any new permission in the new update?

Comment: We added basic permissions like notification etc...earlier versions of the app also didn't get updated...

Comment: As far as I know, the app doesn't update automatically when you add a new permission in that update. So you might look out for that

Answer (score 0):

Just wait.  Google has to handle thousands of apps every hour, so it usually takes 3+ hours to get an update across the ecosystem.

Comment: It's been more than 24 hrs and it's not updated...earlier versions of the app also didn't get auto updated...